# Modify variables inside self-invoking functions

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

I have been hung up on this for a while. I am wondering if there is any way to modify a variable inside an anonymous self-invoking function from outside of its scope?

Here's some sample code to help clarify:

```
(function(x, y, z) {
var annoyances = "normal functions";
console.log(annoyances);
})(window, document, undefined);
```

What I am hoping to do is to change the value of annoyances to:

```
annoyances = "self-invoking functions";
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions create a scope for the variables, so the variables are not visible outside of it. But you can do vice versa. Create a variable outside of the self invoked function and use it inside it. Functions can access the variables in the scope where it was defined.

```
let annoyances;

(function(x, y, z) {
   annoyances = "normal functions";
   console.log(annoyances);
})(window, document, undefined);
```